# xRM-Portals Cryptographic Operation Error - settings.xml corrupted

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, portal, dynamics-crm-portals

I have a running installation of xRM Portals with Dynamics 365 8.2 On-premise. Everything works fine. ButI have the problem, that the `settings.xml` file gets corrupted every night - I can't explain why. I have the problem described in the following blogpost:

https://dynamics365authority.com/Blog/adxcrm-portal-cryptographic-operation-error-while-opening-adx-portal-from-iis

After deleting the `settings.xml` and reconfiguration everything works fine. But just for one day. After returning to the office the next day, the settings are again broken.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution here: https://github.com/Adoxio/xRM-Portals-Community-Edition/issues/99

Due to daily app pool recycling we had a new auto generated machine key every day. With a dedicated machine key in the web.config this problem is solved! The password hash uses the machine key.